# Scala: Adding elements to Set inside 'foreach' doesn't persist

Tags: scala

I create a mutable set and iterate over a list using a 'foreach' to populate the set. When I print the set inside the foreach, it prints the contents of the set correctly. However, the set is empty after the end of 'foreach'. I am not able to figure out what I am missing.

```
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

object SparkTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Spark Test")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val graph = GraphLoader.edgeListFile(sc, "followers.txt")
    val edgeList = graph.edges

    var mapperResults = iterateMapper(edgeList)

    sc.stop()
  }

  def iterateMapper(edges: EdgeRDD[Int, Int]) : scala.collection.mutable.Set[(VertexId, VertexId)] = {
    var mapperResults = scala.collection.mutable.Set[(VertexId, VertexId)]()
    val mappedValues = edges.mapValues(edge => (edge.srcId, edge.dstId)) ++ edges.mapValues(edge => (edge.dstId, edge.srcId))
    mappedValues.foreach {
      edge => {
        var src = edge.attr._1
        var dst = edge.attr._2
        mapperResults += ((src, dst))
      }
    }
    println(mapperResults)
    return mapperResults
  }
}
```

This is the code I'm working with. It is a modified example from Spark.

The

```
println(mapperResults)
```

prints out an empty set.

Comment: Works just fine when I try it in the REPL.

Comment: It works for me from REPL too. But doesn't from my .scala code!

Comment: Maybe lst is empty then?

Comment: No, lst is not empty. Whatever I add to the set inside foreach, gets printed. The problem is only after the foreach when the set turns out to be empty.

Comment: Show us a complete, executable, example

Comment: Edited question with the code I'm using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it works, but in the worker.
the foreach is a function that exists for the side effects, but it work on the worker, so you wont see the updated Set.
Other issue is that it design to be Immutable!  so do not use mutable collection there.  Also there is no need for that.  The following code should do what do you meant to do:

```
var mapperResults = mappedValues.map(_.attr).distinct.collect
```

It shorter, cleaner and do the map work on the workers.